# how to and input files to apk that can be read from C++?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I use JNI to develop my app, and there are two .dat files used as input files in C++ layer. At present, I push these two files into mobile devices through adb before open related app. I think there is a better solution to prevent from pushing two files into mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

after trying several solutions, I have solved it by combining three solutions, and the code shown below. Before using the code, you need to create a folder called "assets" parallel to "res" folder. Through this way, you can attach the input file you may use to the apk, and when installing the apk first time, it will automatically store the files to specific path in the target device.

```
public class CameraPreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements CameraPermissionHelper.CameraPermissionCallback {


SharedPreferences prefs = null;


public static String TAG = "CameraPreviewActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.yourcompany.yourapp", MODE_PRIVATE);

}




@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)){
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        try {
            final InputStream input = getResources().getAssets().open("face_model.dat");

            try {
                File UPLOAD_DIR = new File("/sdcard");
                File file = new File(UPLOAD_DIR, "face_model.dat");
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    try {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                        int read;

                        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                        output.flush();
                    } finally {
                        output.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // handle exception, define IOException and others
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            final InputStream input = getResources().getAssets().open("shape_pred.dat");

            try {
                File UPLOAD_DIR = new File("/sdcard");
                File file = new File(UPLOAD_DIR, "shape_pred.dat");
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    try {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                        int read;

                        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                        output.flush();
                    } finally {
                        output.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // handle exception, define IOException and others
                }
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}